# Como apontar para um arquivo FXML no javafx

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Criei um projeto do zero, estava sem nenhuma pasta e abria a janela perfeitamente, porém quando eu coloquei dentro de 7 pastas e então começou a não carregar. Alguém sabe como eu apontaria? Estou utilizando o Scene Builder tambem.

A arvore é assim:

```
projeto
└───src
    └───br
        └───com
            └───mask
                └───tarefas
                    └───login
                        └───LoginSystem (arquivo que tem que apontar para o FXML)
                        |
                        └───layout
                            └───LoginFXML (ArquivoFXML que tem que ser apontado)
```

A classe que aponta é essa:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LoginSystem extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("LoginFXML.fxml"));
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Em que pasta o arquivo ```LoginFXML.fxml``` está?

Comment: Esta na ultima pasta,layout, ja o System que chama ele esta uma pasta antes, login

Answer (score 0):

Bom, resolvi apontando o arquivo controller dentro do arquivo FXML

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
            fx:controller="br.com.mask.tarefas.login.layout.LoginFXMLController">
```

E logo depois criei uma URL dentro do arquivo LoginSystem(arquivo que aponta para o FXML) e coloquei ele dentro do Pane ao inves de criar la dentro.

```
URL arquivoFXML = getClass().getResource("/br/com/mask/tarefas/login/layout/LoginFXML.fxml");
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(arquivoFXML);
```

Comment: Recomendo vc criar uma classe utilitária que tenha um método em que vc passe ```"LoginFXML.fxml"``` e ele retorne ```"/br/com/mask/tarefas/login/layout/LoginFXML.fxml"```, se não você vai ter que repetir esse caminho toda vez que você for carregar um arquivo FXML.